# Why won't my dataframe show the added column?

Tags: r, dataframe, correlation

I'm working with a data set and created a data frame to make a new column (bty_average) which is the mean of 6 other columns in the data frame. While it says it is created and allows me to plot bty_average, it does not show up when I view the data frame. What is wrong?

Current code below.

```
Evaldf <- Eval
Evaldf %>%
  mutate(
    (bty_average =                                             
    bty_f1lower+bty_f1upper+bty_f2upper+bty_m1lower+bty_m1upper+bty_m2upper)/6
  )
```

I've also tried creating it like this, to no avail:

```
bty_average <- ((Evaldf$bty_f1lower + Evaldf$bty_f1upper + Evaldf$bty_f2upper + Evaldf$bty_m1lower + Evaldf$bty_m1upper + Evaldf$bty_m2upper)/6)
```

Comment: Please check the `str(Eval)`.  It is not clear without a reproducible example.

Comment: your first code example should create an output with the the column if *Evaldf*  is a dataframe with the respective columns (of appropriate type).  However you are not changing the dataframe itself, so a subsequent `View(Evaldf)` won't contain it until you assign the output, e.g. `Evaldf <- Evaldf %>% mutate(...)`

Comment: Just like if you have `x <- 5`, if you enter `x + 1` you see the result `6`, but `x` is unchanged. If you want `x` to change you need `x <- x + 1`. If you want `Evaldf` to change, you need `Evaldf <- Evaldf %>% mutate...`